# Is it possible to parse and streaming the Audio data using AVaudioplayer in iOS without using audioqueue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

Our projects is about parse and streaming the audio data from iP-camera. is it possible to streaming the audio data using avaudioplayer without using audioqueue?